# How to put method calls in a stack

Tags: java, automated-tests, callstack

Is there a way to put a collection of different method calls(along with different list of parameters) in a stack using java?
I intend to execute a pop-call on the stack and see these methods executed in LIFO sequence.

Assumption: All the methods belong to a single class.

Comment: There is nothing "built in"; you would have to create your own data structure, and fill it manually. On the other hand: why do you want this information? Besides: only use tags that have something to do with the content of your question; like not using `devops` on a pure java code question. If you want to check that certain methods are called ... then I would recommend to start looking into unit tests and how to use them to test for expected behavior of your classes.

Comment: Thanks @Jägermeister. And I am sorry for tagging wrong group, first time.